# .svn folders using a lot of disk space

Tags: svn, space, disk

today I realized that the hidden .svn folders within my folders under version control eat up ~16 GB of hard drive space. I am using a SSD drive so this is quite a lot. Do I really need these huge subfolders? As far as I understand they are used for administration but why are they approximately the same size as the folder under version control itself?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you store in the repository?

Comment: Files and documents. I basically use SVN to sync between my laptop and my tower PC.

Comment: Keep in mind that Apache Subversion is a version-control system. In other words, it's not an ordinary file storage-sync tool but it can perform such task.

Answer (score 2):

These folders are necessary as long as you want to use SVN version control system. They are used to keep trace of your local version changes in order to commit your work and checkout (eventually merging with your information) upstream data.

If don't want to use version control anymore you could delete all .svn folders. If you don't mind keeping history you could make a clean checkout, delete .svn folders and then create a new repository.

Comment: Thank you! There is no way to have this folder on the server and have the local folder compared to the server version?

Comment: If you delete .svn folders you lose the "relationship" between your SVN repository (what you call server version) and your local copy and also all the connected capabilities (like revision comparing, ect...).

Answer (score 2):

The `.svn/text-base/` directories contain un-changed versions of the version-control files.  This accounts for your duplication and similar size to the directories outside of `.svn`.  These files enable certain operations to be streamlined (e.g. diffs).

Advantages of this approach, as mentioned in [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.developer.insidewc.html) include:

> network-free checks for local modifications and difference reporting,
>   network-free reversion of modified or missing files, more efficient
>   transmission of changes to the server